# How do you get the type of a primitive literal in Java?

Tags: java, int, long-integer

I just learned about using "L" after long values to signify that they're long types, just like when you use "f" after float types.  I was wondering what happens when you write;

```
long value = 3;
```

instead of

```
long value = 3L;
```

So I was wondering;

*Does the compiler consider 3 an integer and then just convert it implicitly to a long?*

Then I tried to check the type of the value "3" by using instanceof (but I can't use it since it is a primitive type) or reflection (getClass(), but obviously I can't because it isn't a reference type).  **Is there anyway to check what type the value "3" is or is this impossible since Java is statically typed?**

Thanks,
Bernard

Comment: No @DontKnowMuchButGettingBetter

Comment: Why not? Please show your code using the answers from that question, and tell how it doesn't work.

Comment: Because the OP is not talking about the type of a *field* but the type of an *expression*.

Comment: We know that the `3` is an int literal; that's a given. And Java automatically casts it to long

Comment: System.out.println(3 == Long.TYPE);

Gives me "Incompatible operand types int and Class<Long>"

Comment: @BernardBorg: that's not how the code in the answers work or are written

Comment: @DontKnowMuchButGettingBetter: "We know that the `3` is an int literal; that's a given." – That is *literally* the answer.

Comment: It's not useful to _check_ the type of `3`, because it's always `int`.

Comment: @Sweeper So the answer is no?

Comment: @BernardBorg: You can easily check the type of `3` by looking it up in the JLS.

Comment: @JörgWMittag So there isn't anyway to do check the type of primitive literals with code?

Comment: A literal is literally the value it represents. The literal is composed of a sequence of 'marks' (my term) in source code. You can always determine the type by looking at the marks, and as a programmer you need to know how to do that -- you need to know 3 is an int, 3L is a long int, '3' is a char, and "3" is a string.

Comment: @BernardBorg: It's not necessarily the case that there is no way. There is just no need. `3` is always `3`. There is no need to check what `3` is because you know what it is. Its value and type is uniquely determined by the sequence of characters that appears in the source code.

Answer (score 1):

According to [section 3.10.1 *Integer Literals*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.1) of the Java 14 Language Specification:

> An integer literal is of type `long` if it is suffixed with an ASCII letter `L` or `l` (ell); otherwise it is of type `int` ([§4.2.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.1)).

Comment: This answers my initial question of whether "3" is int or long, but doesn't answer the question whether or not there is any way to check the type of a primitive value.

Comment: @BernardBorg: again, the answers in the duplicate question answers this "second part" completely.

Comment: @BernardBorg: The Java Language Specification tells you the type of `3`. You can check it by looking it up there.

Comment: A literal is literally the value it represents. The literal is composed of a sequence of 'marks' (my term) in source code. You can always determine the type by looking at the marks, and as a programmer you need to know how to do that -- you need to know 3 is an int, 3L is a long int, '3' is a char, and "3" is a string.  So given you must know this when you write the code, there is no need for runtime facilities to check.